# Split the PageModel logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have mvvm asp.net the application and PageModel have quite a lot of logic. The question is how it can be divided.
The logic represents get and post methods (create, update, delete, etc.) over a given structure.

```
public class A
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<B> List { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The structure is approximate. Data is received and processed through the repository.

If I use partialview, I can only split my cshtml file, but the pagemodel will remain the same. As I understand it, I need to use a complete representation inside, only how to do it correctly

Comment: There are loads of ways to separate logic out of a PageModel class, but without any understanding of what "quite a lot of logic" means, it's very difficult to provide any useful suggestions.

Comment: @Mike Brind I have completed the post. I hope it became clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> The logic represents get and post methods (create, update, delete,
> etc.) over a given structure.

This sounds more like an MVC controller, where all operations for a single entity are crammed into a single file. This is not how Razor Pages is designed to work. Razor Pages is a "page-centric" framework, where each CRUD operation should have its own page and associated PageModel. Sure this increases the number of files in the application, but the contents are simplified. Therefore you should only have one `OnGet` and one `OnPost` method in each PageModel class.

The contents of your Create page and Edit page are likely to share common elements (form fields, for example). Those can be separated out to a Partial.

Comment: I understand that. But that's what it says in the test assignment. That the application should be mvvm and be on the single page.

Comment: Then Razor Pages is the wrong framework for you. It sounds like they want you to use a JavaScript MVVM framework like KnockoutJS, or possibly Blazor (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor). I know there are blog articles etc that describe Razor Pages as MVVM, but it's not.